# Stress test Java application proxy utility

Tags: java, proxy, stress-testing, utility

I wrote a standalone Java utility, it acts as a Proxy that internally invokes operations on the MBean remotely hosted on the Tomcat JVM. (Several Java based client applications initializes new instances of it to update MBeans). What are available approaches/tools, to Stress test this Proxy, so as to simulate concurrent users and find out bottle necks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **Fuzzing**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing
- http://www.fuzzing.org/
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fuzzing

This approach can provide you both **stress testing** and **fuzzing I/O to bring out possible bad code** (not handled exceptions, memory insufficiency, etc..)

Comment: Marek, do we have more familiar tools to stress test standalone Java APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a framework to leverage existing Junit tests with Contiperf2. Able to run few of the tests. Seems to be promising.